# Can not Initialize Firebase in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, initialization

I tried to signup in over my html website over live Server (port:5500). All Firebase rules and Web stuff are configured. But the console output of the live server says error in line 19:

```
`(firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`.
```

With the error message

```
firebase.js:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at firebase.js:19:1
(anonymous) @ firebase.js:19
```

This is my Code for the .js File

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

//Init Firestore
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Initialize Firestore
const auth = firebase.auth()
const database = firebase.firestore()
```

and a code snippet of the .html file:

```
<!-- code -->
<body>
    <div class="background-container"></div>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="firebase.js" type="module"></script>
    <!-- Rest of code -->
</body>
<!-- code -->
```

How can I init the firebase firestore in javascript and can i test the connection (sign up a account) over the live server (Port:5500) or do i need to visit my public website url site and test the connection over there.

(secound time using stack overflow forgive me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with live server. The one recommendation I have is that since you're already using `module`, you can move your imports to JavaScript.

So the `index.html` file can be shortened to this:

```
<body>
    <div class="background-container"></div>
    <script src="firebase.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

And the `firebase.js` file can be updated to import statements like this:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-auth.js";
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-firestore.js";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```